# PHP echo not working

Tags: php

I am learning PHP. Currently, I have:

```
<?php
 echo "<p>This text was brought to you by PHP.</p>";
?>
```

What this does is outputs "This text was brought to you by PHP." and then on the next line: "; ?>
I cant figure out what i'm doing wrong, the code is seemingly correct.

PS. I made sure its a php file.

Comment: @HipsterLeprechaun How are you opening the file in your browser? Does the url start with `file://`?

Comment: Are you running the page on a web server with php enabled?

Comment: The url starts with file:///C:/ (windows 8)

Comment: @HipsterLeprechaun There's your problem

Comment: @HipsterLeprechaun PHP is a server side language, your computer/browser can't read it directly. Install XAMPP or WAMP, if you want to get it right take a look at vagrant or install linux on a virtualmachine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot run a php file off the filesystem (file://) you need to install a web server with php enabled and then the server side code will run.